# Какие библиоетки на C# могут дать информацию о запросах юзеров со всего мира с фильтрами по персональным данным?

Tags: c#, google-analytics, аналитика, персональные-данные

Хочу сделать пет-проект на Android (C#), позволяющее подобрать ужин в зависимости от персональных данных группы лиц (день рождения, имя, аллергия) подходящей под конечного пользователя. К примеру, сгруппировать по дате рождения и посмотреть топ запросы для этой группы (например "рецепт паста карбонара") и в зависимости от топа формировать личные предпочтения для пользователя.

Пытался искать подобные сайты но не нашел. Какие есть библиотеки (или что-то другое) на C# для аналитики запросов, где можно сгруппировать  по персональным данным? Я пытался в Google Analytics Api, но я так полагаю это для аналитки уже готового приложения, а мне же нужна библиотека/сайт с доступным API

Comment: Big Data. Такие данные можно купить, за дорого. Вендоров можно поискать. Так что нет ничего невозможного, вопрос бюджета.

Comment: @aepot эх мне хотя бы чуть-чуть этой биг-даты откусить... пока еще нет денег тратиться на пет-проекты(

Comment: @Aarnihauta нет денег - прийдется угадывать)

Answer (score 1):

Персональные данные пользователей - это очень ценная вещь.
Сильно сомневаюсь, что вы сможете найти бесплатную библиотеку, которая так  просто с вами этим поделится.

Но вы всегда можете начать вести свою базу данный в своём приложении.
Пользователи будут регистрироваться у вас в приложении, делиться своими предпочтениями.
А вы уже будете анализировать эти данные и формировать подборки.

Comment: Да проблема ведь в том, что пользователей-то и не будет, это же пет-проект, а если вручную всё заполнять то боюсь очень долго будет. Хотя, можно сделать рандомайзер персональных данных и предпочтений, а там дело за малым, но это конечно жесть будет, слишком уж много и долго надо будет генерировать такое количество данных